# I want to implement a RESTful webservice do i need something om my server running to handle requests , like with SOAP

Tags: android, web-services, json, rest

I want to implement a RESTful webservice  for an Android App using JSON. Do i need something om my server running to make for example a GET request work , like with SOAP is the case. I have read something on servlets but i don't know if this is neccesary or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be using PHP on the server then you can write a RESTful service with a PHP application framework like Kohana, CodeIgniter, CakePHP etc.  There are quite a few.

These frameworks have built in functions for encoding results in JSON format and they support the REST approach out of the box.

If you prefer I'm sure there are also similar IIS and .NET based approaches too.

Comment: Hi Matt, Yes the files on my Server will be php and i have a mysql database that i will need to retrieve some data from. 
So if i understood you right the CakePHP framework will be of better use to me because i can programm the servlet in PHP 
as aposte to the Restlet framework which i would have to program a servlet using Java?

Comment: @jan - yes do it all in PHP, you won't regret that.  Here's a short tutorial. http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rightwayindia/2010/01/11/restful-web-application-development-in-cakephp

Comment: @jan PHP is better suited for small web servers. Servlets and Java are meant for industrial strength webapplications. Also, it depends on what you're already familiar with.

Comment: @bizso09 - what do you base that reasoning on?

Answer (score 1):

If you query your own server, then you need to first program your server to handle requests. On the other hand, if you query a 3rd party RESTful server, then all you need is create the appropriate http request, send it and handle the response.

Servlets are used for Java EE based implementations of servers. You can implement your server in any programming language or framework you want.

Comment: thanks. I think your info is a good supplement to the info given to me beneath.